# scikit KernelDensity returning flat density

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, kernel-density

I'm trying to fit a Kernel density to a time series of S&P Returns. However the resulting density is mostly a constant. I first use stats.gaussian_kde and compare to scikit's Kernel density.

The code is the following:

```
temp_data = mc_data.iloc[idx_r]['SPX Returns'].dropna().values
X_plot = np.linspace(temp_data.min(),temp_data.max(),100)
       
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(temp_data, bw_method='scott')
pdf = kernel.evaluate(X_plot)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(X_plot, pdf, linewidth=3, alpha=0.5)
ax.hist(temp_data, fc='gray', histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.3, density=False)
plt.show()
```

Which yields the following result

[image]

And the second version, using scikit is:

```
k_data = temp_data.reshape(-1,1)
kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=1).fit(k_data)
x_plot = X_plot.reshape(-1,1)
pre_pdf2 = kde.score_samples(x_plot)
pdf2 = np.exp(pre_pdf2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(X_plot, pdf2 , linewidth=3, alpha=0.5)
ax.hist(temp_data, fc='gray', histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.3, density=False)
plt.show()
```

yielding:

[image]

After inspecting the values of pdf2, I can see that is an array of values whose difference with respect to the following position in the array is of the order 10e-8, so pretty much an array of constant values.

Why is KernelDensity not returning a proper density?

Comment: On kde side: Make sure to understand the theory. Then compare bandwidth=scott with bandwidth=1.0. of course ths will effect in pretty different behaviour for most data. You can use gridsearch to cross-vAlidate that param in sklearn. Statsmodels has also optimization-based bw-selection. But there.might be some prob witb your plots too, as the first plot looks too unsmooth.

Comment: Apparently the bandwidth was orders of magnitude off: should be something around 0.002, that's why using 1 returned a flat density

Answer (score 0):

It's because there's some normalisation steps in `sklearn` that must not be included in the `scipy` implementation. You can scale your output yourself, but the quickest fix is just to change the plot:

```
ax.hist(temp_data, fc='gray', histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.3, normed=True)
```

Gives me the right looking plot!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Changing density=False to normed=True does not change my plot :(

Comment: What about if you remove density? Exactly copy what I have done.

Comment: I did, the issue was not the normed, was the bandwidth

Comment: Ah yeah, that makes sense. I used the scott rule, I just assumed it was the plot. Glad you got it fixed though!